# Presenting a ViewController's embedding NavigationController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

So I have a login screen that is a `PageViewController` embedded in a Navigation Controller. In my understanding I have to present the root navigation controller to give my `PageViewController` its Navigation Bar.

Therefore programmatically presenting the `PageViewController` won't work.

I have embedded `PageVC` into `NavVC` by setting `PageVC` as `NavVC`'s root view controller.

What is the most elegant way to go about this? I need to be able to display the `PageViewController` (embedded in its `NavigationController`) from multiple places in the app.

Comment: You are right, you should push UINavigationController instead of PageViewController. Post the code how you are pushing NavVC and embedding PageVC in your NavVC.

Answer (score 1):

On your `PageVC` Declare class method

```
class func viewController () -> PageVC {
    return UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Your Identifier") as! PageVC
}
```

Now where you want to present

```
    let vc =  PageVC.viewController
    let nav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc)
    self.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can use this code wherever needed

Comment: But that would create a new NavVC. That would ignore all settings I have set on the NavVC on my storyboard.

Comment: why you are doing that You should apply Nav settings programatically , with appearance  , that will effect on entire application . However you can give identifier to navigation controller on storyboard and  change `viewController()` Method respectively .

Answer (score 0):

maybe provide a bit more code sample? I can't tell what you're situation is.

One suggestion is to just simply present the navController that contains your `PageViewController` from whatever managing Controller you have, whether it be a `UIViewController` as your initial view, or a `UITabBarController` that you have. In any case, you have to present or set the `UINavigationController` as the root.

Comment: But how would I present that programmatically? I don't have a custom class linked to `NavigationController`. Can you post the line of code that would accomplish that?

Comment: `UIViewController` has an optional property called `navigationController` if you're trying to access it from that direction. Otherwise, you can use the `UIViewController` function `func present(UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)`, and you would write in your navController for the first parameter (`UINavigationController` inherits from `UIViewController`)